# Math operators with and without parentheses

Tags: math-operators, parenthesis

I have made several math operators in my preamble, but now I want to make a minor change (in the output). I will use the gradient operator as an example in the following. The MWE below shows my gradient definition including a small example of usage.

```
\documentclass{memoir} 

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\parentheses{\lparen}{\rparen}
\newcommand{\grad}[1]{\operatorname{grad} \parentheses*{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\grad{\vec{x}} = \grad{2y}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\sin x = \sin (2y)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Currently, I always get parentheses in the ouput:
[image: gradient]

The problem is that I would like the left-hand side without parentheses, but still have parentheses on the right-hand side---depending on whether there is a single or multiple inputs/parameters, as exemplified for the sine:

[image: sine]

I would like to change this globally based on the above example without having to correct any operator notation throughout my document. Is that possible? Or optimal? And how is it best done in general (from scratch)?

(I would prefer automatic scaling of the parentheses.)

Comment: It's not a minor change, unfortunately; the concept of “single symbol” is hard to define as the `\vec{x}` and `x` cases show. If you expect that a “single” argument to `\grad` is always of the form `\vec{...}`, then something can be devised. By the way, it's a very bad idea to automatically use the `*` form of the delimiters; I know it's handy, but it's wrong nonetheless.

Comment: @egreg I expected so. Unfortunately, `\grad` arguments can be of any kind, not just `\vec{...}`. Are you saying that it is not possible to make such a command? (At least not without making use of exotic stuff.)

Comment: At the minimum, a list of the possible “single” arguments not to be braced is needed.

Comment: @egreg Would it help to restrict the "single" argument to single characters and commands (starting with a backslash and containing curly brackets) like `\vec{...}` and `\frac{}{}`?

Comment: it is not clear why you use parentheses at all. `sin 2y`  doesn't need them and neither does `\grad \vec x` (naturally not using the `\grad` definition as in OP). The spacing is indicative enough.

Comment: @jfbu The reason for using parentheses for `sin 2y` is due to another (common) multiplication in my document, e.g. `sin(2y) z`.

Comment: @Thomas It would help; but I'm afraid it's insufficient information.

Comment: @Thomas that common multiplication is usually written as `z \sin{2y}` to avoid the problem.

Comment: @PaulGessler I realize now that my MWE was probably too simple since some (most?) people do not understand why it is necessary. I cannot simply reverse the order of the multiplication since the gradient of a vector is a second order tensor and tensor multiplication does not commute. The idea is to make one operator with parentheses in some cases. Based on egreg's and Mico's answers it seems difficult and like something that should be avoided---unless it is done for the sake of doing it.

Comment: It is always nice to have something automatic, but Mico's approach with `grad/gradp` or `sin/sinp` and you, the human, who decides which one to use has much for it in this case. Naturally egreg, Manuel, Mico and others interested can explain how to do it automatically if the criterion is completely explicit.

Comment: Please see my revised answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on a comment from Paul, my job actually became, perhaps, easier.  Here, I do tests on the argument to `\grad`.  If the argument is a single token (or embraced quantity) OR if it is `\vec{<single token or embraced quantity>}`, the parens are not employed.  Otherwise, they are.

```
\documentclass{memoir} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\parentheses{\lparen}{\rparen}
\newcommand{\npgrad}[1]{\operatorname{grad} {#1}}
\newcommand{\pgrad}[1]{\operatorname{grad} \parentheses*{#1}}
\newcommand\grad[1]{\gradx#1\relax\relax\relax\relax}
\def\gradx#1#2#3\relax{%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax%
    \npgrad{#1}%
  \else
    \ifx\relax#3\relax%
      \ifx\vec#1\npgrad{#1{#2}}\else\pgrad{#1{#2}}\fi
    \else
      \pgrad{#1{#2}{#3}}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\grad{\vec{x}}          &= \grad{2y}\\
\grad{\frac{2w}{y}}     &= \grad{\vec{z}}\\
\grad{p}                &= \grad{\vec{a}\times\vec{b}}\\
\grad{\vec{\mathcal{P}}} &= \grad{\alpha}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if `\grad{2y}` is on the left-hand side? I think the left-right description was just to explain for that particular example. In general, he wants "single" operands (whatever that precisely means; see the comments on the Q) to not have parentheses, while operands containing multiple symbols have the parentheses.

Comment: @PaulGessler That would be a misunderstanding on my part.  I will delete my answer unless I can revise accordingly.

Comment: @PaulGessler Perhaps this is an improvement.

Comment: `\ifx#2\relax` is a bit dangerous if `#2` is braced and starts with two identical tokens, perhaps `\ifx\relax #2` ?

Comment: @jfbu You are right.  I learned (and momentarily forgot) that lesson long ago.  I will fix.

Comment: interesting approach by the way :-) ... you seem not to clean up all `\relax` but that doesn't matter indeed here.

Comment: @jfbu  For some reason that I don't understand, the `\ifx\relax#3\relax` breaks if I leave off the final `\relax`.

Comment: the problem is that if you have `\def\foo #1#2#3C` and `\foo` sees `ABCCCC` it will do `#1<-A`, `#2<-B` and `#3<-<nothing>`. Hence `\ifx\relax#3` has empty `#3` and does in fact `\ifx\relax\ifx` swallowing an `\if` hence the extra `\else`.

Comment: @jfbu Thanks for the explain.  I'll have to dust off my TeXbook and relearn how tokens get assigned.

Comment: the big thing is between delimited and non delimited parameters; I recall learning my trade with parameters delimited with (multiple) space tokens ...

Answer (score 9):

Using the power of the `xparse` package, here's a `\grad` macro that checks if the next char is `(`; if that's the case, it treats the contents of the parentheses as an argument and puts `\parens*{#1}` around the argument automatically. So you can use `\grad A` and `\grad(A)` and the latter would become `\grad\parens*{A}` automatically. Plus, thanks to `xparse`, the macro does grab balanced parentheses, so `\grad(\foo(x))` would treat `\foo(x)` correctly.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xparse,mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\parens{\lparen}{\rparen}
\NewDocumentCommand\grad{d()}{\operatorname{grad}\IfValueT{#1}{\parens*{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\[ \grad \vec x = \grad(\frac{y}{z}) \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for providing a detailed description. I've taken the liberty of fixing a couple of typos

Comment: I see I made a lot of errors (the one with `usepackage` was big!!). Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

For maximum flexibility, I suggest you set up two macros: `\grad` as a basic math operator, and `\gradp`, which takes an argument surrounded by autosized parentheses.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\grad}{grad}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\parens{\lparen}{\rparen}
\newcommand{\gradp}[1]{\grad\parens*{#1}}

\begin{document}
\[
\grad\vec{x} = \gradp{\frac{y}{z}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 but the image is strangely rasterized...

Comment: @jfbu - Yeah, I'm at a site today that doesn't make it easy to upload high-resolution image files. :-(

Comment: ...but it feel so much `dvi2hercules` from 1990.... ;'-)

Comment: @jfbu - Better now? :-)

Comment: @Mico good try but I already upvoted ;-) well better yes, but still does look rasterized ... at least on my screen.

Comment: @Rmano - Wow, `dvi2hercules`?! You must be as old as I am!! :-)

Comment: ...dart, now it's gone. @Mico, I suppose it's a tough call ;-) --- but probably yes

Comment: @Mico oops... perhaps I forgot to reload, because now automagically the image looks very good... ah yes, egreg is behind this !

Comment: @egreg -- Many thanks for the "intervention"! :-)